# How to find/change hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to fix a bug caused by a Hibernate query on my DB, but i can't seem to find where does the query comes from. After enabling `sql` log on hibernate i found where the error is, but don't know how to fix.

> Hibernate query (eclipse log)
>   "update students_classes set student_id=null where student_id=?"
>
> throwing:
>   ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Column 'student_id' cannot be null

The error is thrown at this line:

```
student = studentDAO.save(student);
```

where save comes from

```
public Entity save(Entity entity) throws Exception {
        Entity result = null; 
        try {   
            trimAllStrAttributes(entity);
            result = em.merge(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in AbstractDAO", e);
            throw e;
        }

        return result;
    }


private void trimAllStrAttributes(Entity product) throws IntrospectionException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        final Class c = product.getClass();
        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(c, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
            if (method != null) {
                String name = method.getName();

                // If the current level of Property is of type String
                if (method.getReturnType().equals(String.class)) {
                    String property = (String) method.invoke(product);
                    if (property != null) {
                        try {
                            Method setter = c.getMethod("set" + name.substring(3), new Class<?>[] { String.class });
                            if (setter != null) {
                                setter.invoke(product, property.trim());
                            }
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It can be a mapping problem, so here's my entities:

StudentClasses

```
@Column(name = "student_id")
private Long studentId;

@Column(name = "classes_id")
private Long classesId;
```

Student

```
@AuditJoinTable
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "students_classes", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classes_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Classes> classes;

@NotAudited
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private List<StudentClasses> studentsClasses;
```

What should i do? Change hibernate's query (where to find it?) or is there a problem at the mapping level?

Comment: You should include the stacktrace in the question

Comment: Are  you doing a `setStudentClasses(newClasses)` in your code, replacing the managed collection? What is `trimAllStrAttbributes` doing?

Comment: The relevant part of the stacktrace is already here @meskobalazs. I've edited the post the new method M. Deinum

Answer (score 2):

Error explains itself:

> throwing: ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) **Column 'student_id' cannot be null**

As per your other mappings I can say for sure studentId is the primary key of the table, so, if you don't know the id new entities must have, you must mark the field to make hibernate map it:

Mark studentId as `id` and add an autogenerated value:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long studentId;
```

Hibernate defines five types of identifier generation strategies:

- **AUTO** - either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB
- **TABLE** - table holding the id
- **IDENTITY** - identity column
- **SEQUENCE** - sequence
- **identity copy** – the identity is copied from another entity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the sequence creation configuration for the StudentId primary key.  You have to do two things here.

1. Create a sequence in the database like below..

   ```
     CREATE SEQUENCE STUDENT_SEQ
     MINVALUE 1
     MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
     START WITH 1
     INCREMENT BY 1
     CACHE 20;
   ```
2. Specify the sequence name in the hibernate configuration.

   ```
     @Id
     @SequenceGenerator(name = "StudentSeq", sequenceName="STUDENT_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "StudentSeq")
     @Column(name = "Student_id", nullable = false)
     private Long StudentId;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be, that in this line

```
result = em.merge(entity);
```

the `entity` object does not have a set `studentId` property, an that causes the exception. So you need to set it yourself, or generate it automatically, as an other answer suggests.